# Making use of the base path in Laravel 5 (Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I am using laravel in a project. On my local machine the server I have to access is just

`laraveltest.dev`. When I open this URL the project works fine and without problems.

However, when I upload this on a testing server, where the stuff is located in a sub-foder, like this: `laraveltest.de/test2/`. The public folder is at `laraveltest.de/test2/public/`, but when calling `laraveltest.de/test2/public` the application always returns an 404 error.

I thought this might be because of the base path, so I did the following in the `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../') . env('APP_BASE_PATH')
);
```

where `env('APP_BASE_PATH')` is the subfolder.

So `app->basePath()` returns `/var/www/laraveltest/test2/public`. However, when now opening

`laraveltest.de/test2/public` I'm always getting the 404 error and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: whats in the root folder? i wouldn't manipulate laravel files. I guess there might be a solution using htaccess

Comment: You can see the root folder here 

https://github.com/laravel/lumen

The app.php in the bootstrap folder is meant to be modified

Comment: Simple solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740023/redirect-root-of-web-server-to-the-public-folder-in-lumen/30802957#30802957

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **don't** need to change `basePath`, except if you use custom folder application structure. Kinda like this:

```
bootstrap
├── app.php
└── autoload.php
config
├── app.php
├── auth.php
├── cache.php
├── compile.php
[...]
src
└── Traviola
    ├── Application.php
    ├── Commands
    │   └── Command.php
    ├── Console
    │   ├── Commands
    [...]
```

So, in your case, all you have to do is:

- Check .htaccess configuration. Does server allow `.htaccess` file to override specific path configuration?
- Check your `public/index.php` file. Change this line:

---

```
/*
|---------------------
| Run The Application
|---------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$app->run();

// into something like this
$app->run($app['request']);
```

Hope this helps.

#### Additional

If you wonder how Lumen does not work in subfolder. You may see `Laravel\Lumen\Application::getPathInfo()` line `1359`. To make Lumen works in subfolder, change this method, just make a class that extends `Laravel\Lumen\Application`.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Laravel\Lumen\Application as BaseApplication;

class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    /**
     * Get the current HTTP path info.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPathInfo()
    {
        $query = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';

        return '/'.ltrim(
            str_replace(
                '?'.$query,
                '',
                str_replace(
                    rtrim(
                        str_replace(
                            last(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])),
                            '',
                            $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
                        ),
                    '/'),
                    '',
                    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
                )
            ),
        '/');
    }
}
```

Then, in you `bootstrap/app.php`, change this:

```
/*
|------------------------
| Create The Application
|------------------------
|
| Here we will load the environment and create the application instance
| that serves as the central piece of this framework. We'll use this
| application as an "IoC" container and router for this framework.
|
*/

$app = new App\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

After this, you don't need to change `public/index.php` file, just let it default:

```
/*
|---------------------
| Run The Application
|---------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$app->run();
```

Comment: Thanks! The stuff with the `$app['request']` worked. However, my routes are in fact not working. The index page works, but when I'm calling another page, I'm getting a 404 error (not the laravel one, the one from apache) This is the route `$app->get('/post/tag/{tag}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostController@getPostsByTag');` which is working normally on a local machine

Comment: Negative. Even with the additional stuff routes are not working on subfolders. :/

Comment: Your Apache web server has been misconfigured. Please read [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file). And make sure your server load [mod_rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite).

Comment: Thanks. I'll call my server administrator and get back to you

Comment: Ok, that was the error. The server has `AllowOverride` set to `None` by default. He changed it for the site to `All`

Comment: Yeah works now, thus accepeted your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: The Additional section saved me after an entire day of researching and debugging. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**tested with Lumen 5.4 / apache / FPM/FastCGI:**

folder structure:

```
/api
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
/lumen-api/
├── app
├── bootstrap
..
```

Web Root: `/`
URL: http://www.domain.dev/api

copy Files from directory `/lumen-api/public` to  `/api`

change `/api/index.php`:

**1) adapt path to directory with lumen bootstrap**

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../lumen-api/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**2) fix wrong baseURL**
add this after "$app = require __DIR_...." to fix wrong baseURL of /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php:protected function prepareBaseUrl()

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']='index.php';
```

**3) sample `/lumen-api/routes/web.php`:**

```
$app->get('/api/', ['as' => 'home',function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version() . " - " . route('home');
}]);
```

**4) Test `http://www.domain.dev/api`**
**Result should be:**

```
Lumen (5.4.0) (Laravel Components 5.4.*) - http://www.domain.dev/api
```

if you get `http://www.domain.dev/api/api` **two times `/api/api`** - the fix for the baseURL from 2) is not working!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I moved .htaccess from public directory to root directory and created an index.php file in my project root and its looks like this. If you have a laravel project you can copy its server.php from root and change its name to index.php

## index.php

```
<?php

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```