# Redirect to public folder on Lumen (Laravel)

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, lumen

I have a big problem. I work on an application in localhost with Lumen framework. 
My work environment is on Wamp (Windows).

Lumen requires the root to be in the `public` folder.

To do that, I have a configuration file like this :

```
NameVirtualHost name.local
<VirtualHost name.local>    
  DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/name/public
  ServerName name.local  
</VirtualHost>
```

So, if I put the address `name.local/` in my browser, I can reach to the index page.

Now, I need to put all my work in a FTP. And there, I have an exception error, which is normal because my root isn't the `public` folder.

**UPDATE : I have find the answer, please see it below.**

Comment: FTP? file transfer protocol? or some other TLA (three-letter acronym)

Comment: yes, using a software like filezilla

Comment: ftp has nothing to do with php... what is this exception error, exactly?

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, used tags. this : `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.`

Comment: Your question is not clear enough please calm down and elaborate your problem more clearly, it may take a couple of minutes to type but it will definitely get you an appropriate answer

Comment: It all depends on your server and hosting provider. If you can, use a similar virtual host config file. If not, you probably have access to some kind of control panel where you can set the document root of your domain/website

Comment: Ok thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, after days of search, I have found the solution.

Add a `.htaccess` file in the root of the application and add this in this file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Assuming you haven't touched the original architecture of Lumen, and that public data is still in the same place : the `public/` folder

**EDIT :**

With the last version of Lumen and Laravel, you just could write it in the `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Or follow the second method of [this tutorial](http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/)

Comment: Great solution, especially for those hosts that force you to call the folder 'public_html'.

Comment: really worked!!!