# How to change the Public directory path in Lumen?

Tags: lumen

By default Lumen *"same as Laravel"* has `myApp/public` directory to put all the public files (assets).

I want to change that directory path from `myApp/public` to `myApp/src/custom/public`. How can I do achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to change the location of the public directory out of interest?

Comment: yes I want to change the location of the public directory. Because I will have multiple public directories. And I want my app to load from different public directories dynamically, (example if the request subdomain is app1.localhost I want to load the public directory of /src/app1/public).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same problem, and solved it. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802957/3452348), maybe it will help you.
I have done this solution for my Lumen application, which works for me.

**UPDATE**

Ok, let's go proceeding some changes to make the system to work with your tree.

1. Add a `.htaccess` file in the root of your application so in the directory `myApp\`. Write it in :

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
   RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ src/custom/public/$1 [L,NC]
   ```

Assuming that you have configured your vhost pointing to `\Path\myApp`, we now accede to the index file of `myApp\src\custom\public\`. If we didn't make any mistakes, then we should get to a page that indicates an error, telling us that the `bootstrap/app.php` file is not found. Logic.

2. We must therefore change the index.php file in the directory `myApp\src\custom\public` :

   Change from this :

   ```
   $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
   ```

   To this :

   ```
   $app = require __DIR__.'/../../../bootstrap/app.php';
   ```

You can now get your home page directly from the path wanted.

Comment: This seems to be the solution. However I tried it and didn't worked!! can you please edit the answer and include a full copy of your `.htaccess` file. It might help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok. I just have made a complete overhaul of my answer :)

Comment: Fantastic this actually work.
Just quick note for others, this answer doesn't work with the `php artisan serve` command. you need to configure which ever server you use and point it to the root directory of your application.

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with this and found a soltuion elsewhere.

I wanted the following directory structure:

```
.hosting root dir
 ├── lumen_app_dir <---
 ├── other_app_dir
 ├── etc...
 └── public_html
     └──lumen_app_public_dir <---
```

So I did the following:

1. Copied the `index.php` and `.htaccess` from `lumen_app_dir/public` to the `lumen_app_public_dir`.
2. Changed the `index.php` there like this:

   ```
   $app = require __DIR__.'/../../lumen_app_dir/bootstrap/app.php';

   $app->run($app['request']);
   ```

   The important part here is, that I had to include `$app['reqest']` as the parameter for run function.

And it just works without any change in the default `.htaccess` file. I can access the Lumen installation at `server.dev/lumen_app_public_dir`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am on shared hosting, so cannot control vhost public directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can override your public directory using the IoC container like this:

```php
App::bind('path.public', function()
{
    return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```

But I prefer to use a symlink to the public folder like this:

```
ln -s public public_html
```

Comment: Your answer is logical, I've been trying this everywhere and still wont work in Lumen.
As fo the second workaround it is still an option but I prefer not to do it this way, instead I prefer to let the application itself handle this and not the sys admin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should "point" your vhost to the new location (assuming you moved/renamed the public dir to your desired path). This is only needed is your server is not yet configured this way.

Then open the index.php from your new location and "fix" the path to bootsrap/app.php

Then open server.php from the Lumen base dir and edit your paths in both locations you find "public" mentioned.

Didn't really test this but looks like it should work. Give it a try.

Comment: I want to dynamically set the public directory. Because I will have multiple public directories `app-1/src/custom/public` and `app-2/src/custom/public` and when I call the subdomain `app1.something.com` I want to to look for the public of `app-1/src/custom/public` the same applies to `app2`. I was able to do this with the routes and the views. But yet not with the public directory.

Comment: I'd still go this way, but the server.php should be rewritten to match your subdomain logic. It needs to check if the requested file exists in correct dir and require_once index.php file from correct dir.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to bind the path fro public in the appServiceProvider.php register method:

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
     return __DIR__;  });
```

A reliable way is to go into your public_html/index.php!
I'm using Lumen 6.x and it's work properly.