# Lumen redirect from project root to public folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lumen

I want to create an API service powered by Lumen 5.4 which running in a shared hosting environment.

here's my folder structure

```
/public_html
    |- api
        |- public
            |- index.php
            |- .htaccess
```

the `api` folder is the root of Lumen project.

and now I need to access http://example.com/api/public to access my Lumen project. **What I want is** directly access to http://example.com/api

So I try to put a `.htaccess` in `api` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
</IfModule>
```

What I trying to do is redirect all requests from `api` folder to `public` folder. At the end, requests to `public` folder will all redirect `index.php`

The request was redirected to the `public` folder and Lumen can already process it. But I get `NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 594` error.

I refer to many references and all of them having the same `RewriteRule` as I using. But how come it doesn't work at all on my shared hosting?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [duplicate] http://stackoverflow.com/a/30803239/2119863