# Not found page in Lumen after install

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

I just installed `Lumen` but when I head to its public directory `localhost/lumen/public`,

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

will appear.

I checked `app\Http\routes.php` and changed

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
```

to

```
$app->get('/lumen/public/', function () use ($app) {
```

And it worked.

But this is not the thing I want. In Laravel the `'/'` works perfectly. How can I make Lumen work with `'/'`?

---

BTW when I use `php artisan serv`, `'/'` works but only in artisan serv :(

Comment: You don't want to have the name `public` ?

Comment: Have you defined the vhost ?

Comment: @zlen No. I haven't. The problem is that in Laravel I don't have any problem without doing anything.

Comment: Look my topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30802957/3452348

Comment: In your `index.php` file, change your code into something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728973/notfoundhttpexception-with-lumen/30254364#30254364).

Comment: @KrisanAlfaTimur Thank you. This is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### One Way:

In `/public/index.php` change

```
$app->run();
```

to

```
$app->run($app['request']);
```

---

### Another Way:

This also works too (faster):

```
$app->run($app->make('request'));
```

Comment: Worked for me. Any particular reason why this happens? It worked well without this fix on Homestead

Comment: Why the second solution is too faster? First one is using prepared object, but second way is creating another object!

Comment: Actually this didn't work for me. but instead replacing `$app->run();` with 
`$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);` worked.
But still the problem remains same. I need to have /public in my URL. any suggestions for same?

Comment: both solutions are not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you aren't using php artisan serve, what are you using? If you're using vanilla `php -S` you need to also specify the public directory like so:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

You would need to do this inside of your `lumen` directory.

Comment: I'm using Apache as web server. This won't work in Apache.

Comment: use 0.0.0.0 instaed of localhost