# Lumen failed to open /../vendor/autoload.php

Tags: php, lumen

I started using [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) upon its release in April.

From version 5.0, I already faced this same problem and found a solution ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740023/redirect-root-of-web-server-to-the-public-folder-in-lumen)).

There are some days I proceeded to create a new project in Lumen (5.1). However, by applying the method with the `.htaccess` above, the problem doesn't solve it this time.

Here is the full error :

> Warning: require_once(`path_of_the_project/../vendor/autoload.php`): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `path_of_the_project\bootstrap\app.php` on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '`path_of_the_project\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php`' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in `path_of_the_project\bootstrap\app.php` on line 3

How to fix it?

Comment: are you using composer to install it?

Comment: How about this: `dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php'`? Make sure you have ran: `composer update -vvv` successfully.

Comment: I think that the "trick" in the post you linked to may have messed up the routing for your application. Did you make any modifications to the directory structure because of this? Can you confirm that the file does actually exist? After this, can you confirm that the file is readable by the user that the server runs as?

Comment: @KrisanAlfaTimur Many thanks ! You solved my problem

Comment: @Zl3n you're welcome :D

Comment: I tried installing Lumen yesterday and have the same problem. 

The directory project-name/vendor has been created but it is empty. Is it supposed to contain a file autoload.php?

Comment: @AndyC composer update

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `bootstrap/app.php` file, change:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Into:

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And make sure you have ran `composer update -vvv` **SUCCESSFULLY**.

Comment: What does this -vvv option do ?

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error and resolved it by running the below command from project root folder.

```
composer update -vvv
```