# Lumen framework routes not working inside a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, lumen

My htdocs folder is like the following:
htdocs:
/server - here all the lumen files are located
/client - angular 1 project

How can I redirect that when I type localhost/server in the url it will redirect me to the public folder inside the server folder.

I've written this for the .htaccess inside the /server folder to redirect everything to the public folder.

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: "not working" is almost always a bad error description. What exactly is happening or not happening? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, not working, the routes that I registered in lumen are not accessible for some reason. Could you provide an example of redirecting using htaccess from a subfolder to another folder? I need to redirect all requests from /server/public to just server.

Comment: So you get a 404 error message?

Comment: Have you already looked at the "Related" links in the side bar? http://stackoverflow.com/q/30740023/1741542 looks like it is what you're searching for.